# Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'en'

Tags: angular, localization, internationalization

I have an issue with using internalization in Angular. The issue is that when I use the any of buttons for switching languages, it says: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'en'. I use two languages: English and Ukrainian. 
Here is an example where I see how to implement it: https://keep.google.com/u/0/ .

Here is the code of my header - where I have these buttons:

*header.component.html*:

```
    <mat-toolbar class="nav">
        <span>
        <a class="imgLogo" routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active">
        <img src="/assets/img/logo.png" class="logo">MindCare
        </a>
        <a class="statistics" routerLink="/charts" routerLinkActive="active" i18n>STATISTICS</a>
        <a class="contact" routerLink="/contact-us" i18n>CONTACT</a>
        </span>
        <div fxLayout="row" fxShow="false" fxShow.gt-sm>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let language of languageList">
            <a href="/{{language.code}}/">
                <button mat-button>
                    {{language.label}}
                </button>
            </a>
        </ng-container>
        <a class="reg" routerLink="/registration" routerLinkActive="active" i18n>REGISTRATION</a>
        <a class="log" routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active" i18n>LOGIN</a>
        </div>
    </mat-toolbar>
```

*header.component.ts*:

```
import { Component, OnInit, LOCALE_ID, Inject  } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  languageList = [
  { code: 'en', label: 'English' },
  { code: 'uk', label: 'Українська' }
  ];
  constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) protected localeId: string) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   
  }


}
```

*package.json part:*

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build-locale:en": "ng build --prod --i18n-locale en --i18n-format xlf --i18n-file src/translate/messages.en.xlf --output-path=dist/en --baseHref /en/",
    "build-locale:uk": "ng build --prod --i18n-locale uk --i18n-format xlf --i18n-file src/translate/messages.uk.xlf --output-path=dist/uk --baseHref /uk/",
    "build-locale": "npm run build-locale:en && npm run build-locale:uk"
  }
```

*angular.json part:*

```
"en": {
              "aot": true,      
              "i18nFile": "src/translate/messages.en.xlf",      
              "i18nFormat": "xlf",      
              "i18nLocale": "en",      
              "i18nMissingTranslation": "error" 
            },
            "uk": {
              "aot": true,      
              "i18nFile": "src/translate/messages.uk.xlf",      
              "i18nFormat": "xlf",      
              "i18nLocale": "uk",      
              "i18nMissingTranslation": "error" 
            }
```